# Vite library mode how to include bundeled images into consumer project

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, assets, vite, production

I built a vueJs3 library that uses static images and i used vite to build for production. the output dist had an image folder that includes all assets i had in my public folder.

When importing this library into my other vue3 project (the consumer project), the images used inside of the library were not loaded. the browser was looking for them inside of the consumer project when the assets were on the library project.

this is how i am importing the icons inside my library :

```
<img src="/images/icons/cheveron-left.svg" />
```

Is there a way to make the static asset transfer to the consumer project, or make them stick with the library

Comment: I face the same problem! Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JayWang What i did was import the assets from an assets older inside the src folder (it has to be inside the src folder, due to vite default compiling restrictions) directly inside of the components instead of referencing them by a uri like in teh example. This way they will be compiled into base64 at the end and get bundled with the build artefacts